# Adding Test Credit Card to Apple Pay

Tags: developer-program, sandbox

I'm trying to add a test credit card in my Applet Wallet (with icloud and app store signed in to my developer account).

I found a list of test credit cards available from Apple's page https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/sandbox-testing/

However, most of these cards (tried about 10-15 randomly selected ones), threw either invalid card or unsupported errors.

Has anyone encountered the same issue?

Comment: I’m going to tag this strongly as developer / sandbox so people don’t miss you’re testing in a simulated environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I would do is set my region to one of the supported ones for test and make sure I remove all payment from wallet and settings.

Then create a new sandbox account. The common item is mixing the production stream with sandbox stream and burning your account status in the sandbox.

> Important: If you mistakenly use a sandbox tester account to sign in to a production environment, like iTunes, on your test device instead of your test environment, the sandbox account becomes invalid and can’t be used again. If this happens, create a new sandbox tester account with a new email address.

It’s unlikely your developer account would be valid on device when testing payments in a sandbox with sandbox banking details.

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the sandbox account step. I thought the developer account would suffice.